# How does Kernel allocate COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY to a Process

Tags: linux, memory, centos-7, virtual-memory

It would be really helpful for me if someone can answer my question.

How does Kernel allocate COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY to a process (jvm process)

what criteria is used to determine how much COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY is required by a process.

My current Application server : websphere
Ram:3.5Gb
Heap: 2Gb

When websphere starts up my, COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY is 5.1 Gb .

When websphere is taking a load, COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY is 5.5 Gb, at this point Kernel is killing the Jboss EAP PID.

As a temporary fix i increased my RAM to avoid termination of EAP process id by kernel.

But i would like to find out the criteria Kernel is using to allocate COMMITTED VIRTUAL MEMORY.

Comment: There's quite a bit of documentation on Virtual Memory allocation in the Linux kernel. Have you looked this up or read it yet? Are there parts that aren't making sense to you?  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt  https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1133  https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html